# why migration databases not working in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new with laravel and I want to migrate the table first I change .env information (database name, password,user name)and I made the model and write the proprieties but when I write the command php artisan migrate the tables did not appear in my phpmyadmin database and the following error appears:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge' 
(SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and 
table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') catch (Exception $e) {
 > 664| throw new QueryException( 665| $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), 
$e 666| ); 667| } ...
```

Comment: what is the error and add some more details

Comment: please post the error so people can help you with that and make sure you are connected with your database

Comment: this is the error appeared Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') catch (Exception $e) { > 664| throw new QueryException( 665| $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e 666| ); 667| }

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you create a **blank database** before running the migration.

I suggest you create new user and password in your sql and 

GRANT ALL on <'name_of_your_database'>

Then update your **.env** file same as your database user credentials and migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1. composer du.
2. php artisan make:migration create_model_table.
3. php artisan migrate.

   you must be sure that you entered the right db credintials.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running command in desire project.
Have you created migration file for your model by

```
php artisan make:migration create_model_name
```

Update the column in migration file and then run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: once check in .env file is database username and password. is it correct ? Are you using xamp or wamp for server

Answer (score 0):

If you run your project by `php artisan serve`  turn it off and run it again.
If not you need to check your credentials to your mysql

Comment: how can i run it off?

Comment: Just stop terminal or batch or what ever you ran it on it.

Comment: If you are using windows press `ctrl + c`

Comment: I am using mac laptop